# meshlab colorize curvature (APSS)

Tags: mesh, meshlab, colorize

I'm trying to use Meshlab for my degree, and I have to describe how the "colorize curvature (APSS)" filter works. I'm not very able in this kind of programs, and I can't understand what the different parameters changes in this filter.

Any advice? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to read about that in a book. For example, chapter 3 of the book "Polygon Mesh Processing", by Mario Botsch et al, year 2010.